# Android - populating a UI view in the background

Tags: android, view, background

I have a ViewAnimator whose view 0 is a TableLayout consisting mainly of rows of clickable ImageViews,
and whose view 1 is a welcome screen.  When the app is created, it not only has to fill the ImageViews
dynamically (as it has to know how large each one is), but it does quite a bit of number crunching as
well, so I would like to hide the TableLayout until it is ready for interaction. However, when I make
view 1 visible in onCreate(), the app later throws an exception because it thinks the ImageView has width
and height zero.

Is there a way to initialize a view like this dynamically while another view is in the foreground,
without hardcoding the ImageView sizes in the XML (which I can't really do as it depends on the size
of the screen)?

Here is the relevant part of the main XML:

```
<ViewAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/MainView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/TheGridView" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"> 

            <ImageView android:id="@+id/TheImageView"
                android:tag="tag_TheImageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="#FF0"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="TheImageView_Clicked"
                android:layout_margin="2dip"                    
                android:contentDescription="@string/TheImageView"
```

And here is the code in MainActivity.java that is causing the problem (it is in a method called from onCreate()):

```
TableLayout ScreenLayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.TheGridView);
ImageView V = (ImageView)ScreenLayout.findViewWithTag("tag_TheImageView");
int ButtonWidth = V.getWidth();
int ButtonHeight = V.getHeight();
Bitmap ButtonBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(ButtonWidth, ButtonHeight, Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Note that changing the TableRow's layout_height to a value > 0 had no effect - it still thinks the size is 0 x 0 .

Answer (score 0):

that is because the imageview literally has width and height zero, when onCreate executes nothing is visible or drawn yet. you have to put that code in onWindowFocusChanged lifecycle method.

Comment: Actually, the code works if the TableLayout (ID TheGridView) is in the foreground.  The problems are, (a) the ImageViews appear, but they appear as designed in the XML, and (b) I don't want to show the UI until it is ready to accept input.

Does the TableView have to be visible at some point in order for me to accomplish what I am trying to do (by filling in the backgrounds in code)?

Comment: have you tried with V.setVisibilty(View.INVISIBLE) and then bring it up front?